# Where in Timber is file prepared searching query?

Tags: php, twig, timber

In search form searching parameter is send by GET

```
http://site_url/?s=searching_text
```

How is preparing the sql query or where is the file  preparing the query?

search form in Twig:

```
{% block searchform %}

    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form form" action="{{ site.url }}/">
        <label>
            <span class="screen-reader-text">{{ __('Search for:', 'g5_helium') }}</span>
            <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="{{ __( 'Szukaj …', 'g5_helium' ) }}" value="" name="s" title="{{ __('Search for:', 'g5_helium') }}" />
        </label>
        <p></p>
        <input type="submit" class="search-submit button button-small" value="Szukaj" />
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You are looking at a template. The actually code performing the search will be in  php file.

Answer (score 4):

The file is logically named search.php, it can look something like this :

```
$templates = array( 'search.twig', 'archive.twig', 'index.twig' );
$context          = Timber::get_context();
$context['title'] = get_search_query();
$text_search = get_search_query();


$args = array(
    'post_type'        => array('post', 'product'),
    'posts_per_page'   => 8,
    's'                => $text_search,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'paged'            => $paged
);

$context['pagination'] = Timber::get_pagination();
$context['posts'] = new Timber\PostQuery($args);
$context['count'] = new WP_Query($args);

Timber::render('templates/search.twig', $context);
```

That's in case you use pagination in search results.
Here the results are from "posts" but also a custom post type called "products", but you can customize that query at will.